# how to set event on last td of last tr of tbody,in html table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

here is my html table i want to set event on last td of last tr of tbody,
    so please guide me how can i do that in jquery.
i have tried by first and last selector but can't get proper result

```
 <table id="product_table" style="width: 600px;padding: 20px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="background-color: yellow;">
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Rate</th>
                        <th>Disc(%)</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <tr class="tr" style="background-color: ivory;">
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_name" class="product_name" value=""></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_qty" class="product_qty" value="1" onblur="set_total($(this))"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_rate" class="product_rate" value="0.00" onblur="set_total($(this))"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_disc" class="product_disc" value="0.00" onblur="set_total($(this))"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_total" class="product_total" value="0.00" disabled="disabled"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" onclick="delete_product($(this))"></td>
                                                    </tr><tr class="tr" style="background-color: ivory;">
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_name" class="product_name" value=""></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_qty" class="product_qty" value="1" onblur="set_total($(this))"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_rate" class="product_rate" value="0.00" onblur="set_total($(this))"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_disc" class="product_disc" value="0.00" onblur="set_total($(this))"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_total" class="product_total" value="0.00" disabled="disabled"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" onclick="delete_product($(this))"></td>
                                                    </tr><tr class="tr" style="background-color: ivory;">
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_name" class="product_name" value=""></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_qty" class="product_qty" value="1" onblur="set_total($(this))"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_rate" class="product_rate" value="0.00" onblur="set_total($(this))"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_disc" class="product_disc" value="0.00" onblur="set_total($(this))"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" id="product_total" class="product_total" value="0.00" disabled="disabled"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" onclick="delete_product($(this))"></td>
                                                    </tr></tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6"><input type="button" id="btn_product" class="btn_product" value="Add Product"></td>
                    </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="4"><div style="float: right">Grand Total</div></td>
                <td style="background-color: ivory;"><input type="text" class="grand_total" id="grand_total" value="0.00"></td>    
                <td></td>
            </tr></tfoot>
        </table>
```

Comment: `$('#product_table tbody tr:last td:last').on(....` http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `last-child` selector at this context to get your job done,

```
$('table tr td:last-child').click(function(){
   // your code
});
```

[A demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z49t6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

One more version that's partially based on Rajaprabhu-Aravindasamy's solution:

```
$('table tr:last-child td:last-child').click(function(event){

  (event.target).innerHTML ="works";

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/Dp6JR/154/)

This only works on the last row.

Comment: thanks for this,it works fine for simple text in cell,but i have a textbox in html table cell and want to set blur event on this

Comment: @Priyank if your textbox has an id, then i think this might work: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_blur.asp  I mean just attach an event handler for the blur event and the textbox

Comment: solved using jquery,replace the code at,                      $('table tr:last-child td:last-child input').click(function(event){

  $(this).val("works");

});